# Why destroy() method doesn't work in my tkinter program?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, methods

why, when I use the destroy() method, the program does not close?
I tried to use Nick.destroy(), root.destroy() and self.destroy() and none of them work.
Tries to close the window when the user types in the correct nickname and passes it out of class

```
from tkinter import *

class Nick(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Nick, self).__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.mes = None
        self.count = 0
        self.lbl = Label(self, text="WPROWADZ NICK").grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.ent =Entry(self)
        self.ent.grid(row=2, column=1)
        btn = Button(self, text="Akceptuj", command=self.accept)
        btn.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.error = Label(self, text="")
        self.error.grid(row=3, column=1)

    def accept(self):
        self.mes = self.ent.get()
        if len(self.mes) == 0:
            self.error.config(text="Nick nie moze byc pusty")
        elif " " in self.mes:
            self.error.config(text="Nick nie moze zawierac spacji")
        else:
            global mes
            mes = self.mes
            Nick.destroy()
        if self.count == 0:
            self.error.config(text="")
            self.count+=1

def main_tk():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("ONLINE CHAT")
    root.geometry("260x100")
    app = Nick(root)
    root.mainloop()

main_tk()
print(mes)
```

Comment: You're calling `destroy` on a class rather than on an instance of a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest fix would be to replace `Nick.destroy()` with `self.master.destroy()`

This is why the ones you've tried do not work:

- `Nick.destroy()`: `Nick` class has no @classmethod called `destroy`
- `root.destroy()`: `root` is only accessible in the main method and `.mainloop` is blocking. So by the time you exit from the main loop (via closing the program, ctrl + c, etc) there's no need to destroy the root.
- `self.destroy()`:  destroying the `Nick` class would only destroy the `Frame` it inherits from and thus and will not close the entire program

Comment: `self.destroy()` should work, since `self` is a widget and thus inherits the `destroy` method.

Comment: @Fabian_Olczak, if this answer addresses your question please mark it as accepted so others can find the solution to the problem quickly